# ReactJS asynchronous returns

Tags: reactjs

I have read some Stack Overflow questions about ReactJS and asynchronous returns, but I don't get it.

I have StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-p4j4ts

What should I do in order to make my HTML page show "Loading..." in these areas what are not loaded yet, but changes the text as soon as the content is ready to show up? I would like to make a page load faster (asynchronously) if I have some kind of data-fetch going on in the background instead of letting users wait so long.

It seems that ReactJS supports standard modules like 'fs' and others so this asynchronous issue is the only case I want to know and verify it's working for until I start full courses about ReactJS.

Are there some simple examples that would help me understand this issue?

Comment: Your `Hello` component does nothing other than return "Loading...". Are you asking why react isn't rerendering it?

Comment: Well, start your React course, you will learn what are React lifecycles, how does it render and re-render

Comment: Since it seems to possible. I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React uses state and props. When either update the component will be re-rendered.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(); // <--- state

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setData("Response Wanted"); // <--- update state
    }, 3000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer); // <--- clear timeout when component unmounts
  }, []); // <--- run effect when component mounts, i.e. setTimeout

  return data ? data : "Loading..."; // <--- conditionally render loading or data
}
```

[image: Edit charming-davinci-7238u]